# Predictin population with lm() in R. Summary returning "ALL 10 residuals are 0"

Tags: r, linear-regression

I'm trying to predict the population of the state in the year 2025, based on data from 2010-2019. My CSV file looks like this (for brevity purposes, I 'll just post the first three years)

```
 Year     Population
 2010     375,344
 2011     378,522
 2012     381,222
```

I'm running into two issues. First off, the below code gives me "Residuals:
ALL 10 residuals are 0: no residual degrees of freedom!" and below that states:

Residual standard error: NaN on 0 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:      1, Adjusted R-squared:    NaN 
F-statistic:   NaN on 9 and 0 DF,  p-value: NA"

```
model <-lm(formula = Population ~ Year, data = pop_OK)

summary(model)
```

Secondly, I'm not sure how to use lm to predict 5 years into the future. I saw an example on how to do it, if you've typed your data into a datagram, but not a csv. Any ideas or links I can look at? (I prefer that than just answers, if possible).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably your `Population` is not numeric. Try to `transform` after cleaning with `gsub`.

```
pop_OK <- read.table(text="Year     Population
 2010     375,344
 2011     378,522
 2012     381,222
", header=TRUE)

pop_OK <- transform(pop_OK, 
                    Population=as.numeric(gsub("\\D", "", Population)))
```

To `predict` we want a new dependent variable in a `data.frame` including the years to be predicted.

```
model <- lm(Population ~ Year, pop_OK)
pred <- predict(model, newdata=data.frame(Year=2020:2025))
setNames(pred, 2020:2025)
# 2020     2021     2022     2023     2024     2025 
# 404813.7 407752.7 410691.7 413630.7 416569.7 419508.7
```